# getQuantityString not replacing the format with the value

Tags: android

I want to uses the plurals resource to produce a quoted number like `"9"`.

In my `plurals.xml`:

```
<plurals name="posts">
  <item quantity="other">\"%dd\"<\item>
</plurals>
```

The code:

```
String text = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.posts, meUser.postCount);
```

When the `postCount` is 9, why does `text` turn out to be `"%dd"` and not `"9"`?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

From [the Android docs:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals)

> When using the `getQuantityString()` method, you need to pass the
>   count twice if your string includes string formatting with a number.
>   For example, for the string `%d` songs found, the first count
>   parameter selects the appropriate plural string and the second count
>   parameter is inserted into the `%d` placeholder. If your plural
>   strings do not include string formatting, you don't need to pass the
>   third parameter to `getQuantityString`.

ie `res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.numberOfSongsAvailable, count, count);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some strange reason, just adding the third parameter (same as second parameter) did solve my issue (although I have only one count in string)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone has a brain-fail like me today and still cannot get it working.

I had accidentally left my emulator in a non-English locale which meant my "one" translation was being ignored!

(Only the "other" entry was being used in my case)